# Line spacing in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to program my medical practices EMR. Here is the code that prints our patient's medication list:

```
<FONT POINT="10">
&SQLNUMBERED&SQLMRGN02&SQLTRIM&SQLCOMMA
&{SELECT PRESCRIPTI,INSTRUCTIO FROM CLRXHIST WHERE COMPANY='&COMPANY' AND SSNO='&MRNO' AND ACTIVEFLAG='Y'}
```

and produces the following output:

1. Multiple Vitamins Essentials Multiple Vitamins, 1 tablet by mouth daily
2. Niacin 500 mg Tablet, 2 tablets by mouth daily
3. OTC supplements variable, take as directed
4. Simvastatin 40 mg Tablet, 1 tablet by mouth daily

How can I increase the spacing between each line?

Comment: Argh, my eyes! My beautiful eyes!

Comment: The code you posted isn't SQL (well, a bit of it sort of is) - you need to tell us what you are using to produce your reports.

Comment: @RobbMD: This a fragment -- it would be easier to be helpful if you gave all/more of the code... for example your example starts with `&` and ends with `}`, not very helpful to us.  That said it might help you to know that in html you want `"<BR/>"` and in text you want `"\n\r"`, in VB you want vbCRLF...

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to touch the SQL. You want to change the code that turns the query result into output.